# C# Chart Date tooltip works only for the first series

Tags: c#, charts, linechart

```
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh MM/dd/yyyy";

foreach(item in Collection)
{
            myChart.Series.Add(station.Name);
            myChart.Series[station.Name].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            myChart.Series[station.Name].BorderWidth = 3;
            myChart.Series[station.Name].ToolTip = "#SERIESNAME \r\n Date: #VALX \r\n Value: #VALY";
}
```

Here I have this C# winform code with the intention of displaying tooltip when a user mouse hover on the chart. The date and values are expected to be displayed but it only works for the first Series in the chart. For the rest of the series it will display the date as 0.

Any solution?

Comment: Post code of how you databind / add points to the series

Comment: What are item, Collection and station?

Comment: It is way simplier to set the tooltip `foreach(DataPoint p in yourChart.Series.Points)`